# Receive input for multiple simpledialog popup windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to programming so please bear with me if my question is too silly but I haven't been able to wrap my head around this yet. I am trying to build a simple "rock, paper, scissors" game in Python using the GUI tkinter. How could I create a loop with these popup windows?

This is what I have so far, how could I turn this into a loop so the game could continue? Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import simpledialog

def press():

    header = simpledialog.askstring("Welcome", "Please enter your name")

root = Tk()


button = Button(root, text="Let's PLAY!", command=press)

button.pack()


NEW

import random


def rock():
    pass


def paper():
    pass


def scissors():
    pass


start = ""

response = [rock, paper, scissors]
ai_response = random.choice(response)

while start != "quit":
    start = input(">>> ").lower()
    if start == "play":
  print('You are about the play "ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS"')

 elif start == "1":
        print("""
You have chosen 1 ?! 
rookie.... """)
        if start == "paper":
            print(ai_response())
```

Comment: What are you looking to use the `for` loop for?

Comment: I would like for this to be a popup interactive game where the users enters a value (paper) and the computer will generate a random from (rock, paper, scissor). I am not sure how to make these windows to show in a loop as I would also like for the game to run 2/3 or 3/5 or etc.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a loop to open new windows in tinter. If you're using a loop in this case it's only to check what a user has chosen (rock, paper, or scissors). Otherwise it's more of using `if` parameters.

Comment: Are you not using `root.mainloop()` ?

Comment: and why are you not importing `tkinter` ?

Comment: as my level of programming is so low I decided to leave the GUI for maybe next month when my understanding of python will be better. I am trying now to do the same thing but very basic and of course I got stuck again. here's what I got:

Comment: i've updated my post as the the comment section messes the code up. ai_response() doesn't generate a random answer and i'm not sure why. thanks again everybody!

Comment: and to answer the above questions: I did user root.mainloop, it was something more like 
`root.geometry("smthXsmth:)`

`root.mainloop()`

my way of importing was

`from tkinter import*`

`from tkinter import simpledialog`